# Is there a package available for Spacebars in Meteor to do thinks like {{bind-attr}} or {{link-to}} like in Ember?

Tags: ember.js, meteor, spacebars

I know of the basic functions of *Spacebars*, but cannot seem to find anything similar to `{{bind-attr class=""}}` or `{{link-to}}` like in handlebars in *Ember* for example.

The best I could find it to manually create these, but wanted to first check if there was a more straight-forward method in meteor, or if not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meteor's spacebars does provide similar functionality through slightly different methods.

similar to bind-attr meteor has [dynamic attributes](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/spacebars/README.md#dynamic-attributes)

> A double-braced tag can be used in an HTML start tag to specify an
>   arbitrary set of attributes:
>
> ```
> <div {{attrs}}>...</div>
> ```
>
> The tag must evaluate to an object
>   that serves as a dictionary of attribute name and value strings.

Or alternatively, or in combination, you can use the double-braced tags within your attributes to provide dynamic content as in:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checky {{moreClasses}}" checked={{isChecked}}>
```

Regarding link-to, meteor does not directly provide a solution, but since it is within the context of routing, you should check out your router's capabilities. Meteor's defacto router is the third party package called [Iron Router](https://atmospherejs.com/iron/router) which actually provides exactly the same solution with its [linkTo helper](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#linkto)

> ```
> {{#linkTo route="post.show" data=getData query="q=s" hash="hashFrag" class="my-cls"}}
>   <span style="color: orange;">
>     Post Show
>   </span>
> {{/linkTo}}
> ```
>
> The expression above will be transformed into html that looks like this:
>
> ```
> <a href="/posts/1?q=s#hashFrag" class="my-cls">
>   <span style="color: orange;">
>     Post Show
>   </span>
> </a>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using **iron-router**, https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#linkto[iron-router](https://atmospherejs.com/iron/router), there are a number of helpers available, including [linkTo](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#linkto).